# React Material Table : onRowAdd not refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, material-table

I am using Material Table for displaying table data.
Using onRowAdd, I am able to add a new row but the page is not refershing. It reloads and get stuck then I have to reload it again.

```
newData =>
                            new Promise(resolve => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    resolve();
                                    this.setState(prevState => {
                                        this.props.saveSetting(newData, this.state.resource, "generalmessage.successMessage");
                                        const data = [...prevState.data];
                                        
                                        return { ...prevState, data };
                                    });
                                }, 600);
                            })
```

Save Setting is the function that I am calling in sagas.

I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here.
Please guide me in this.

Comment: please add the related part with your component which needs to be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using `useState` in your component.
Anyway, I did my `onRowAdd` this way and it's working:

```
            onRowAdd: (newRow) =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTableData([...tableData, newRow]);
            setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500);
          })
```

Hope this helps